# Merge Lists in Dictionary and remove duplicates

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I only found questions where people wanted to merge lists into dictionaries or merge dictionaries but not merge lists that are already in a dictionary

Lets say I have a Dictionary having following structure

```
myDict= {
  'key1': [{'description': 'some description', 'listwithstrings': ['somestring1'], 'number': '1'}, {'listwithstrings': ['somestring1', 'somestring2'], 'description': 'some other description', 'number': '1'}],
  'key2': [{'listwithstrings': ['somestring4'], 'description': "some different description, 'number': '2'}, {'number': '2', 'listwithstrings': ['somestring5'], 'description': 'some different description'}],
  'key3': [{'number': '3', 'listwithstrings': ['somestring7', 'somestring8'], 'description': 'only one entry'}]
  }
```

now I want to merge the entries in the dictionary from each key for itself and remove the duplicates. I don't know for each key whether it has multiple entries (it can have more than two, too) or just one, so I can't use the key as a condition like `number==1`

Resulting in

```
myCleanedDict= {
  'key1': [{'description': ['some description', 'some other description'], 'listwithstrings': ['somestring1', 'somestring2'], 'number': '1'}],
  'key2': [{'listwithstrings': ['somestring4', 'somestring5'], 'description': 'some different description', 'number': '2'}],
  'key3': [{'number': '3', 'listwithstrings': ['somestring7', 'somestring8'], 'description': 'only one entry'}]
  }
```

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you always have the same keys in your list of dicts (In your example: 'number', 'description', 'listwithstrings')?

Comment: yes, they are always the same and I know the names of these keys.

Answer (score 0):

```py
myDict = {
    'key1': [
        {
            'description': 'some description', 
            'listwithstrings': ['somestring1'], 
            'number': '1'
        }, 
        {
            'listwithstrings': ['somestring1', 'somestring2'], 
            'description': 'some other description', 
            'number': '1'
        }
    ],
    'key2': [
        {
            'listwithstrings': ['somestring4'], 
            'description': 'some different description', 
            'number': '2'
        }, 
        {
            'number': '2', 
            'listwithstrings': ['somestring5'], 
            'description': 'some different description'
        }
    ],
    'key3': [
        {
            'number': '3', 
            'listwithstrings': ['somestring7', 'somestring8'], 
            'description': 'only one entry'
        }
    ]
}

newDict = {}
for k, v in myDict.items():
    if len(v) == 0: continue
    target = v[0]
    for k in target:
        if not isinstance(target[k], list):
            target[k] = [target[k]]
    for i in range(1, len(v)):
        for k, v in v[i].items():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                target[k] += v
            else:
                target[k].append(v)
            target[k] = list(set(target[k]))
    for k in target:
        if len(target[k]) == 1:
            target[k] = target[k][0]
    newDict[k] = [target]

print(newDict)
```

Comment: I get the error message 'str' object has no attribute 'items' and even then my dict looks totally different than excepted, e.g., 'somestring1' is still there two times even though it should have been only kept one time.

Comment: @matlabalt I edited it. If you are getting error  the you probably inputting different structure then is in answer. I cannot really account for more then I know about.

Comment: It's still wrong. `myDict` still has double entries and not only one where everything is merged as asked.